# Android layouts within layouts, with separate classes handling their input?

Tags: android, xml, layout

Hey all,
I have created a program in Java that uses Jpanels within Jpanels. One example of this is having a side view containing buttons that change the main view when pressed. The main view also has buttons that can be used to alter itself.

I am trying to re-create this on the android. I have my layout set up from an xml, with a side panel containing buttons and the main view.

There is another xml that contains what I want in the main view.

Now I am struggling to get this separate xml to be displayed in the main view and can’t figure out how I would get the class to handle its own input. I don’t want to paste the code into the main.xml as I want to keep things object orientated and each view needs some custom elements such as different textviews.

An example of what I am trying to convert for the android is below:-

```
//The ViewInt class has its own layout
ViewInt tempView = new ViewInt(i, mFloorNo);
//The viewInt class is then added to the main window.
mainWindowPanel.add(tempView);
```

This small bit of code would create a view, add it to the main view and then any input in the main window is handled by that class, but at the same time any input not in this main window is handled by another class (probably the root class).
Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

To clarify:
The program has a side panel layout, containing buttons. And a main view layout that is empty. I am trying to set a .xml layout to this main view layout, and have it so that if any buttons are pressed in that main view then a class for that layout will handle it.

Comment: i don't fully understand your question, what you want to do are nested views with custom content? also you want to handle the device input events separatelly on each view? i don't really understand your question, since one and only one view has the focus at time...

Comment: Maybe views is the wrong word. I might mean layouts. There is a layout for the side panel which has some buttons, and a layout in the main view which has some buttons too. These are both contained in another layout, which is the root layout, containing everything. The main view is changeable, so I am looking for some way of adding/removing layouts to this. Also i would like to have a class for each layout that will be in charge of its own layouts button presses.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to do, then I would extend one of the layout classes to create my panel classes and then simply nest them in another layout (RelativeLayout perhaps) in the main.xml layout file.

```
public class MyPanel extends LinearLayout
    implements Button.onClickListener {
    // Do things which are common to the side & main panels in this class
}

public class MySidePanel extends MyPanel {
}

public class MyMainPanel extends MyPanel {
}
```

Then in the res/layout/main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <com.mydomain.MySidePanel
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/side_panel_layout"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sp_Button1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <!-- Do other button -->
    </com.mydomain.MySidePanel>
    <com.mydomain.MyMainPanel>
    <!-- main panel layout here -->
    </com.mydomain.MyMainPanel
</RelativeLayout>
```

In the above I've obviously only put one button in the side panel and left the main panel empty but you should be able to see my approach from that. You also need to add the relative layout android:layout_ properties.

In your activity, just setContentView(...) and create instances of your panel classes.

**EDIT:** I meant to mention that although the above seems to set the overall layout absolutely, there's nothing stopping you from creating new MyMainPanel layouts at runtime and swapping them in place of the original in the RelativeLayout parent.